# How to export 802.1x WLAN configuration from a device to another device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, authentication

I've a Windows machine that connects to WLAN using 802.1x. I want to use 802.1x with another machine to let it connect to WLAN too.

I've always thought it was as easy as exporting a WLAN profile and certificate using e.g. the `netsh wlan` command.

https://community.arubanetworks.com/t5/ArubaOS-and-Controllers/802-1x-Machine-and-User-Authentication/td-p/8886

> The way the "enforce machine auth" auth works is by keeping track of
>   which machines (by mac address) have successfully passed 802.1x with
>   their machine credentials (for AD this is their computer name/account)
>   and applying a role derivation scheme that takes this into
>   consideration when they pass 802.1x authentication with their user
>   credentials.

However, as the above article describes, Active Directory authentication is performed both for the machine and user accounts? It doesn't mention certificates at all.

The 802.1x security settings for my Windows machine is as follows:

```
Authentication         : WPA2-Enterprise
Cipher                 : CCMP
Authentication         : WPA2-Enterprise
Cipher                 : GCMP
Security key           : Absent
802.1X                 : Enabled
EAP type               : Microsoft: Protected EAP (PEAP)
802.1X auth credential : Machine credential
Cache user information : Yes
```

So, is it possible to transfer 802.1x betwteen machines?

Comment: The certificates are how the machine or user account is identified, aren't they? Which method is used will depend on the network.

Comment: No, as I understand, 802.1x authenticates using either credentials or certificates? Please elaborate.